# Php echo content into div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to insert html and javascript which is generated in php into a div in the page.

a.php file:

```
function get_preset() {
    return (bunch of html, javascript);
}
```

b.php:

```
<div id="preset_preview">
    //<?php echo get_preset(); ?> //this works well, but I need to execute this every time I click a button in jquery.
</div>
```

I can use ajax to communicate between my jquery and a.php successfully, but how do I place returned content from get_preset function call in php into preset_preview div?

Is there a way to do this **without** sending data with ajax from get_preset function call into jquery, then use jquery to put this into preset_preview div?

Can php somehow do it alone each time on request from jquery like this?

So I use jquery ajax to call php to execute this:

```
<div id="preset_preview">
    <?php echo get_preset(); ?>
</div>
```

What is confusing to me is that php can do it successfully (as example above demonstrates) without sending data with ajax to jquery first.

Comment: Sounds like you need to learn about the difference beween clientside and serverside scripts to answer whatever it is you are asking.

Comment: You can include a.php file in b.php file and then call `get_preset()` in your b.php file, and when you need data you ajax call b.php

Comment: Please try to explain what you actually want to do whith this code. Like what will do the JS and HTML just for example. So that we can provide more help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a.php file

```
function get_preset() {
    return (bunch of html, javascript);
}

echo get_preset();
```

b.php file

```
<button type="button" id="preview">Preview Preset</button>
<div id="preset_preview">
    <?php include "a.php"; ?>
</div>

<script>
    $('#preview').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#preset_preview").load('a.php');
    });
</script>
```

There are several methods of jQuery AJAX which you can actually use. Example above is using [`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) which wraps your request with get method (you can override its request method by calling [`ajaxSetup()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/), anyways) to relative URL of a.php.

You can see a.php `echo`ing (string of?) `get_preset()` function which will then placed inside `<div id="preset_preview">` in b.php file.

---

To expand the needs of AJAX in this case is because PHP only does something like

1. Getting a request, no matter what the method is (get, post, put, etc)
2. Returns a response. Usually after you do some logic related to request value.

It dies whenever your *expected* response rendered to client side. You can't do anything magic behind the wall right after response is returned. In the other word, a page load is needed.

And then AJAX comes to help you create another request to corresponding PHP file. It revives a PHP file to do (another) request -> do some logic -> then do returning it. Silently, without a page load.

And in respond of comment -- *Can this be done with function calls somehow without including the actual php file in preset_preview?*

It's all yes. As long as you serve whatever the caller needs.

a.php file

```
function get_preset() {
    return (bunch of html, javascript);
}

echo get_preset();
```

The a.php is simply `echo`ing `get_preset()`.

b.php

```
<button type="button" id="preview">Preview Preset</button>
<div id="preset_preview"></div>

<script>
    $('#preview').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#preset_preview").load('a.php');
    });
</script>
```

The b.php file is simply doing a request to a.php file. Whenever the button with selector id `#preview` is clicked it will load whatever a.php content to `#preset_preview`.

You can also render the content of a.php just after the page ready. This is similar approach like my first snippet as written on above.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#preset_preview').load('a.php');
    });

    $('#preview').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#preset_preview").load('a.php');
    });
</script>
```

It simply tells you that you should load a.php right after the b.php page is *ready* and "reload" it once the button clicked.

Comment: Yes, get_preset echoes string. So content of a.php will not be visible inside a b.php until load('a.php') is called?

Comment: Actually no, since `<?php include "a.php"; ?>`. But you can do similar approach by listening on page load or with `$(document).ready()` which mean then you should write the `load()` method twice.

Comment: But I only need to include a.php on my request (or just the string content of get_preset function call), not like the example above. Not sure what is the point of load above since a.php is included immediately. That is exactly my question here but I dont know how to execute it.

Comment: _But I only need to include a.php on my request_ -- on click event? Sure, remove `<?php include "a.php"; ?>` or make blank element with recognized selector will do.

Comment: The a.php should serve whatever your b.php needs. That's why I did an `echo` in a.php. If you still want the b.php to handle the request, I'll update my post with some workarounds.

Comment: Can this be done with function calls somehow without including the actual php file in preset_preview?